# Cannot get text from button using BeautifulSoup Python

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I have a page from where I want to get the text from a button which I think is controlled by js

```
<button class="shop-tab js-shop-tab icon location-tab single-shop "><span>Location</span></button>
```

I try

```
location = soup.select('location-tab').text

location = soup.find('button', attrs={'class':'shop-tab js-shop-tab icon location-tab single-shop'}).text
```

as I would with selenium like

```
location = post.find_element_by_css_selector(".location-tab").text
```

But I get NoneType
How can I get it with Beautifulsoup?
thank you

Comment: The `text` you're trying to get is "Location"?

Comment: Its a phrase in Greek like Athens from a url like https://www.skroutz.gr/s/2195774/Western-Digital-Blue-3-5-1TB-7200rpm.html

Comment: So the button has other text that's populated by (you suspect) Javascript code, and that text that's populated by JS is what you're trying to get?

Comment: yes that is correct

Comment: Then it sounds to me that this is a timing issue. You're getting the text before its been generated therefore its "none". With selenium strategy is pretty subjective based on the target. If you can give me an sample page I can give you some suggestions.

Comment: https://www.skroutz.gr/s/2195774/Western-Digital-Blue-3-5-1TB-7200rpm.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191482/discussion-between-evridiki-and-codespent).

Comment: What text/button do you need to get? i only see Greek, nothing is written in english.

Comment: @Pedro 'Μαρούσι, Αττική'  next to rating stars

Comment: That info is being loaded by a xhr query, when you click *the button*,  this json's parsed: https://www.skroutz.gr/m/summary/5426/2195774. product_id: 2195774 shop_id: 5426. Change this values accordingly and you get pretty much what's on that page.

Comment: @Pedro which means? Why I can get with selenium and not with BeautifulSoup?

Comment: You can, actually mix both, first get all shop/product id from page with selenium, then, construct the url with vendor/product and make the request directly.

Comment: The info you need to parse in on: `<li class="card js-product-card" data-shopid="5458" data-product-id="43804187" data-shop-review-score="" data-shop-reviews-count="0">` Let me make a quick script to exemplify.

Comment: sounds more complicated..

Answer (score 0):

Following the comments on the main question, to get the information of all shops selling the product, you can use:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html = requests.get("https://www.skroutz.gr/s/2195774/Western-Digital-Blue-3-5-1TB-7200rpm.html").text
soup=BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
lis = soup.findAll("li", {"class": "card js-product-card"})
for li in lis:
    shop_id = li["data-shopid"]
    prod_id = li["data-product-id"]
    # get shop inforamtion
    si = requests.get(f"https://skroutz.gr/m/summary/{shop_id}/{prod_id}").json()
    # si now contains a clean json object with all the shop info, phone, full_address, coordinates, etc.
```

---

```
{'shop': {'id': 3964, 'name': 'Mdstore', 'url': '/m/3964/Mdstore', 'logo_url': '//c.scdn.gr/ds/shops/logos/3964/mid_20170103102940_411b7fcf.jpeg', 'latest_reviews_count': 40, 'new_review_url': '/account/shops/reviews/new?shop_id=3964', 'review_stats_per_impression': [{'impression': 'positive', 'impression_text': 'Θετικές', 'percentage': 85, 'count': 34}, {'impression': 'negative', 'impression_text': 'Αρνητικές', 'percentage': 15, 'count': 6}], 'locations': [{'id': 5271, 'lat': '38.056695', 'lng': '23.806215', 'info': '', 'feature_description': 'Κατάστημα & Σημείο παραλαβής.', 'phone2': '2106141179', 'pickup_point': True, 'store': True, 'visible_on_product_card': True, 'phone': '2106141118', 'full_address': 'Διονύσου 3, Τ.Κ. 15124, Μαρούσι, Αττική', 'distance': 10.4, 'distance_tier': 3, 'address': {'city': 'Μαρούσι', 'region': 'Αττική', 'street': 'Διονύσου 3', 'postcode': 'Τ.Κ. 15124', 'full': 'Διονύσου 3, Τ.Κ. 15124, Μαρούσι, Αττική', 'structured': True}}], 'paypal': False, 'phone': '2106141179', 'reviews_label': 'αξιολογήσεις', 'is_reseller': False, 'official_reseller_text': '', 'formatted_latest_review_score': '4,3', 'rating_percent': 86, 'details_icons': [], 'has_pickup_points': True, 'time_on_platform_in_words': ['2', 'χρόνια'], 'orders_to_range': '50+', 'top_reasons': ['Έγκαιρη παράδοση', 'Φιλική εξυπηρέτηση', 'Προσεγμένη συσκευασία προϊόντων'], 'closest_store_details': None}}
{'shop': {'id': 2749, 'name': 'Multicopter', 'url': '/m/2749/Multicopter', 'logo_url': '//c.scdn.gr/ds/shops/logos/2749/mid_fba77f19-03b8-421c-bdcd-8853740ab740.png', 'latest_reviews_count': 407, 'new_review_url': '/account/shops/reviews/new?shop_id=2749', 'review_stats_per_impression': [{'impression': 'positive', 'impression_text': 'Θετικές', 'percentage': 99, 'count': 401}, {'impression': 'negative', 'impression_text': 'Αρνητικές', 'percentage': 1, 'count': 6}], 'locations': [{'id': 2760, 'lat': '38.016931', 'lng': '23.649653', 'info': '', 'feature_description': 'Κατάστημα & Σημείο παραλαβής.', 'phone2': '', 'pickup_point': True, 'store': True, 'visible_on_product_card': True, 'phone': '2110125139', 'full_address': 'Αφροδίτης 9, Τ.Κ. 12462, Χαϊδάρι, Αττική', 'distance': 7.7, 'distance_tier': 2, 'address': {'city': 'Χαϊδάρι', 'region': 'Αττική', 'street': 'Αφροδίτης 9', 'postcode': 'Τ.Κ. 12462', 'full': 'Αφροδίτης 9, Τ.Κ. 12462, Χαϊδάρι, Αττική', 'structured': True}}], 'paypal': False, 'phone': '2110125139', 'reviews_label': 'αξιολογήσεις', 'is_reseller': False, 'official_reseller_text': '', 'formatted_latest_review_score': '4,7', 'rating_percent': 94, 'details_icons': [], 'has_pickup_points': True, 'time_on_platform_in_words': ['3+', 'χρόνια'], 'orders_to_range': '100+', 'top_reasons': ['Έγκαιρη παράδοση', 'Φιλική εξυπηρέτηση', 'Ενημέρωση για την εξέλιξη της παραγγελίας'], 'closest_store_details': None}}
...
```

---

Note:
Moderate your requests or google re-captcha will bug you.

Comment: Looks great!!! but how to get the text of 'region'. What do you suggest to moderate my requests? Is soup.findAll("li", {"class": "card js-product-card"})[:5] will do something?

Comment: In regards to moderate the requests, you'll have to add valid headers to the requests ( navigate to the webpage on a regular browser and copy the request headers it generated to a dictionary, then add it to requests: `requests.get(url, headers=headers)`). 20 requests per minute should be slow enough to not get caught. GL

Comment: "*Is `soup.findAll("li", {"class": "card js-product-card"})` will do something?*", yes, it grabs all data attributes from `li` elements with class `card js-product-card`. This  will be used to construct the request url.

Comment: "*Is `soup.findAll("li", {"class": "card js-product-card"})` will do something?*", yes, it grabs all data attributes from `li` elements with class `card js-product-card` , that will be used on the request.